# Postgresql and Python: Insert UTF-8 string

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to insert a list of strings into a Postgres table.

The strings are folder names, gathered from a Windows machine, then rewritten to a unix-style string.

This works, but when there is a foldername with "üöä" the insert does not fail, but inserts an empty string.

Here is the code that I use to insert the values:

```
def db_insert_paths(paths):
    paths.sort()
    for path in paths:
        print(path)
        print(type(path))

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO rasp (folder) VALUES (%s)", (path,))

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return 0
```

Here are some examples:
I also captured the traffic sent to the Postgres server.

```
/mnt/hdd/Bilder/2004/2004.08.15. Dorffest
<class 'str'>

INSERT INTO rasp (folder) VALUES ('/mnt/hdd/Bilder/2004/2004.08.15. Dorffest')
```

This insert works. The data is in the table.

However, the next one doesn't:

```
/mnt/hdd/Bilder/2004/2004.08.30. Filterschacht räumen und reinigen
<class 'str'>

INSERT INTO rasp (folder) VALUES ('/mnt/hdd/Bilder/2004/2004.08.30. Filterschacht r��umen und reinigen')
```

[image: Wireshark capture]

The entry is empty.

What am I doing wrong here? I am guessing it is some kind of encoding fail.

I am using python3.4 on Windows 8.1, with Postgresql 9.5. The field type is "text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is encode your string here. So

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO rasp (folder) VALUES (%s)", (path.encode('utf-8',))
```

And when you want to read it from the db you'll just decode it with `path.decode('utf-8')`

Alternatively, you could change your db character set: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html#AEN32089

Comment: Thanks. I would like to avoid using encode() and decode(). Manually inserting the string (in phppgadmin) works like expected.
Collation is `en_US.UTF-8` and Character Type is also `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Can you manually view the string in the database? I wonder if phppgadmin automatically encodes the string for you.

Comment: This thread seems relevant: https://sourceforge.net/p/phppgadmin/bugs/250/

Comment: You might be right: https://i.imgur.com/KbmO9Eq.png
In this special case phppgadmin does not display the string. If I enter a somewhat shorter string with no date, it displays the umlauts correctly.
I tested beforehand by inserting a "äöü", which worked, thus expecting that phppgadmin works correctly. The first line should show the string from the opening post. It does show correctly in a normal query outside phppgadmin. I'll accept your answer since you brought me to the right track. :)